# Multiple grep commands with sort

Tags: text-processing, grep

I have a text file containing a list of student grades:

```
Andrew cooking A
Andrew cooking B
Andrew computing F
Steven java C
Steven python E
Ben C++ D
Ben python C
Jamie java E
Jamie C++ E
Jamie C++ B
Jamie python E
Gerry python E
Phil python F
```

I am trying to use the grep command to show all python results, sorted from best to worst grade. The file is called `a.txt`. I have tried `grep python a.txt | sort -d` which doesn't work, so I was looking for a bit of help on this.
Thanks

Comment: You need to *key* the sort on the grade (third) field e.g. `sort -dk3`

Comment: Yeah i just worked this out and now in the process of deleting xD Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

Use that command:

```
awk '$2=="python"{print}' a.txt | sort -dk3
```

If the second field is `python` print the whole line and let it `sort` on the 3rd field.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not familiar with `awk` you might find following solution easier to grasp:

```
grep "python" a.txt | sort -dk 3 | cut -d " " -f 1,3
```

- `grep` selects lines that contain given word
- `sort` is sorting in descending order based on third key
- `cut` is getting rid of the 'python' word. If it is showing in every line, it does not bring any information into the picture.

Result:

```
Ben C
Gerry E
Jamie E
Steven E
Phil F
```